# Create file from JFIF data

Tags: php, ldap, jpeg

I have a dump of our LDAP database, and i'm attempting to extract all images from it using PHP. The images seem to be stored in JFIF format (at least, according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#page-5). However, i can't figure out how to create a JPEG file from this; I attempted `file_put_contents` to dump everything in name.jpeg, `imagecreatefromstring`'s output to `imagejpeg` and some variations on those. However, either I'm not using them correctly, or I'm just attempting this wrong alltogether.

So the question:

Here's a small part of the field:

```
jpegPhoto:: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2Mi4wICh1c2lu
 ZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0IHF1YWxpdHkK/9sAQwAIBgYHBgUIBwcHCQkICgwUDQwLCww
 ZEhMPFB0aHx4dGhwcICQuJyAiLCMcHCg3KSwwMTQ0NB8nOT04MjwuMzQy/9sAQwEJCQkMCwwYDQ0YMi
 EcITIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIy/8AAEQgAh
 QBkAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMF
 BQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU
 2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpq
 eoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5+v/EAB8BAAMBA
 QEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEH
 YXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFl
 aY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8
 jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A8Kihad+OB3JrQhtI7aHzG
 bdKTwMdBVKSGWFVc7lDZAPTOOv6H9aTzJlKMGO4gEH26VEk31Jaua8MkSpIHk3dSkWw854J/wDrUtzb
 uCTuYkZDZH5VW06AMwIZss/DZweo5H51ptKzM6SYJGAGIwSMfr0rnk+WWhk9GYzR+Y4AJUgd/wDP0qN
 2JVDjnOM5zjGP6VoXVsUl+Rcbjk4qg8Xlz5429Qf6VtGSaNYu6G4U5U9fX3qOJC7bTzn0qY5HDYwe9M
 CxhnBYnP3QO9WO5s6aJmiZWUtDyN+/P4dfxrNu0PmH50ZckEgd+P8AGpYbkwxBInOxnVmU9Diku49jj
 zBiQruYcdT/APqrKKtIhaMcZ43i+WLAJOVx9wdsEf1pXhLQbg4Y7QSBywHqR6VAYGNusq8ZBIGc8Vct
 4WuLZsEJLHgq464zx/P9KTtHVCehmHGeKKVm3Mfl2kHBorY3jsWdRMEKGOJneRuGbOBjPYf/AK+vam2
 tlLdyLwxiVdq5OOP/ANZps22/mSO1tyNueVyWfknp7AVq28epwsWS2i3MRjkg8e3+e1ZSbjHzM/IoXQ
 MLGDYy7eg24I44/p+daFgwW32zKEf1GCT7/wCf14ANQgvzGHvhCsY2lvL6yAnO0n/PaqUTie9CQYCIy
 sGkPcZOCB1qLc8bE8rehqXkYOShLBRg4B6+/wBax7iLazyj8P8A9da4a5ub1BbW7yuQobaOCP8AP/1q
 dq+jXcFq13Gr+Wg/exsuMf4j/PvRTTjoy405JXsYEkxMYdMg+wquOVznOfyqxG0bNtyUXIxgZP06j3q
 ybZJWaTgj2Xk/X9TmtnJRJvYrwMnlMGbkHg+3tUcmAzrnPINWBED90cDjgdO9VpF2kZ/A5oVmwRfi1R
 CY4p4cQKclE7gdun07jv8AhM6IiGVZAVYlGMZ6Hg4+nPXJBrIVSwwqlvoKnVTDleOcdqlwS2BrsLduX
 m5UAgAEgYz70UlzKJpdwHbH60VcdjWOxp6XbwQLGsvmi4c5UL2A5+b245/+tVmVxbhpd4jKrjaG3Yb2
 Bz+ntWaLS4gKEzukh+UAgHr7/j+tPeBY5d8l0ZZEPCngZ9vzrBxTd7mbJUmvDbkGA7JRkFzyfr7U6zt
 7iVfKikCTzsQ+G6jA5z781KLuWS3YDJRj90jA68gdv8imSSXNvcRvCoLOyhlByDk8fj2/GiL1sVDfU9
 V8LaLb2C7owHkZeTj/AD71p+I4ra90qa0i8o3gQ7EOMsccqAeuRkcZ61y+jXV5d2PnJK0e1AeSOTzwR
 +XXP4V12n3sE8C6jGIVkZR5xL7QTnGD2zzx9abR6KXNE8B1CzOnanNC8JTyzwrnkAgEdhngiq7yyAdw
 pO4Cut+Jkksni5vMiVFWFFiIUjevXJz3ySPwrmI50jK52sw6Bl4z/hWvS5584pSaLCS/aIRKgzIG+cK
 PTpx3qgFEtxtLYUscHHTPfnFXo7oOGJ2oBglF6OM8/T/P0MDQsZJXRVYcHkgZBGcgdSMA1MdGzNaGhG
 La0AQMu44yxHJyM/4U0vZ3csSIzJJJxkDcF5PXpz9PWqwjkEZAJVXAZV3YJI6YqLbi2Y52FSGXOMmoU
 FvcVht5C1vcGJ8ZUdqKhaV5jvkbc3rRWyTS1No7GjiYKMb2XuOo/T8D1rOl8yN2WQHd1DZ5q1He2+xV
 k3E4AIU7fy61UuYcnzI2JU8hT1FTC6epmTwXsqbt7Ej07fX9KlzJhZBuVsgqehB7YrORlTaSoYA8qel
 aJnjkhQlZELHK7W3ACiStshnTaP4nlN8ftigI6hXeLIYnsTnOfwr0fw1IpjZEkVo3fcnGHbBBPsPujO
 PfivB5JXSdtpwQa9V8Bapb6lf2jhmNxbw7JVKgDnv+Yocep1UKjd0zpvGXgyx13w9e6jct9mu9Pt2lS
 dcdByIzzyDz9D07g+ET2syMV3qccZx1r37x/q1paeC9QsC3+l3U0KBCP4QxYEev+rbP1HqK8Mnbr/eP
 HStIJcpjVfvsqQpIkow544IHSpnt3WNpIvuA9DyQP64/Ckx5ZEajhRkn1NaEW1kaPsFweM0+VGRnO8j
 wHzMkE8exzzUDFnQDJwoxirEdu8khhX53LHAAJJ96j8s4CnJIyMA1mrICuOFHT3opxG04oqjVbDRgdV
 981AQ3r+tdRFBpkvEbJvcHLtFj8ODx+h96py6XaxzMSxIJJVVGDt/GslWj1MuYxNgK/Lk+uO1SRxnpn
 rVu509Y2LwsXjxyW6g+lRABPvAYxg8VrFqWqGnchI5xmtTQtXuND1SK8t8krwy5IDDuOKp4VyBjB5pg
 G0k4PB/CqsNOx7R4YUeLNJv9e8UXvlaNGzRiM7CsS9sZUnf8wAIw313AV5jqMNsNRmeyaQ2YlYwmXG8
 Jn5d2OM46471r3vjyXUPDOmaAluLOztV2zeQ2RORjDFcDnO4nnljmsZxtLPC++MHrj8siqSE3cznbZM
```

Comment: you could try base64_decode on it then file_put_contents on the result of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is base64 encoded, decode it first and then save it to a file. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php