# Facebook SDK return profile picture as JFIF, how to convert to JPG/PNG in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, image-conversion, jfif

I'm using cURL to get an image from the Facebook SDK, but the image provided is in JFIF format. I tried to use some functions to convert it, as `imagejpeg()` and `imagepng()`, but my host don't support these. I also tried to decode the file as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791718/create-file-from-jfif-data), but no success either. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
//Image handler
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $jsonresponse['url']);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dataDecoded = base64_decode($data); //Last try with base64 decoder
$fb_image = 'fb_picture.jpg';
file_put_contents($fb_image, $dataDecoded);
```

I got no errors, but the saved image (fb_picture.jpg) isn't readable and have 0KB.

Answer (score 0):

JFIF is already JPEG with aditional metadata about the person in the photo. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#page-5 for more info. JFIF is used specifically for pictures of persons. Your host needs imagejpeg() and bundle to work with jpeg. Install it as a PHP module.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The problem is that the host is a shared host, so I can't install anything on it. It's possible to get the data from FB directly as a JPEG? Or use some other way to "convert" it?

Comment: Well you can try parsing raw HTML returned by FB, but there may be other options.

Comment: Actually, from this FB request I get only the URL. The HTML page that opens is a empty one and the picture come as a automatic download.

Comment: I meant try to parse profile page. fb.me/userid as far as I know. It includes profile pic.